# не могу поворачивать корабль на 360, работает только 180 градусов, LeanTween Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу разобраться почему самолет не может поворачиваться дальше 180 градусов https://youtu.be/-FDWjpgBziA.

```
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            {
                LeanTween.rotateX(gameObject, Mathf.Round(transform.eulerAngles.x + 10), 0.101f);
            }
            else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            {
                LeanTween.rotateX(gameObject, Mathf.Round(transform.eulerAngles.x - 10), 0.101f);
            }
```

Comment: попробуй после rotatex добавить `.setLoopClamp();`  - не уверен что поможет, но авось

Comment: Возможно из-за использования `eulerAngles`
(Лучше данное свойство не читать, а только присваивать)

Answer (score 1):

я видел что то похожее вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU3B3D-52us&ab_channel=MythicLegion) но на английском

[image: 1]
[image: 2]