# Не могу повернуть объект относительно другого объекта на 360

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пример на видео по Y он движется адекватно но вот по x при угле 90 у меня он просто стоит
https://youtu.be/DtObo4HbV9Y

```
public class Asteroid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public float Speed = 3;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x - Time.deltaTime * Speed,0 ,0);
        transform.position = transform.rotation*offset+target.position;
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать прозволное движение по любо оси

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [не могу поворачивать корабль на 360, работает только 180 градусов, LeanTween Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1252387/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-360-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-180-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-leantween-uni)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я видел что то похожее
это может помочь
180-transform.eulerAngles.x - Time.deltaTime * Speed может помочь

оригинальное видео:[на английском](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU3B3D-52us&ab_channel=MythicLegion)

[image: может это поможет]

[image: может это поможет 2.0]

[image: и это]